# Вывести числа в последовательности: 3 6 9 12 15 18 ... с помощью FOR

Tags: javascript

как можно вывести эту последовательность с помощью цикла for?

Comment: А в чём, простите, сложность?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Заголовок цикла for состоит из трёх частей. Первая - объявление счётчика `var i = 3`, справа от знака равно должно быть первое число из последовательности. Вторая - условие выхода из цикла `i < 20`, это обязательная часть. Третья - приращение счётчика на три на каждой итерации `i += 3`, это разница для вашей арифметической прогрессии. В теле цикла выводится в консоль значение счётчка.

```js
for (var i = 3; i < 20; i += 3) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если перебирать все числа - можно взять за основу деление на 3 без остатка

```
for (var i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
  if (i % 3 == 0) console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: А если нужны числа, кратные миллиону? Зачем перебирать *все* числа, если этого можно не делать?

Comment: Это один из вариантов решения. Думаю, кто будет искать ответ по этому вопросу - ему будет интересно посмотреть как можно больше вариантов решения